# Dynamic select table in teradata

Tags: sql, oracle, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I am new to teradata, I am trying to create dynamic table in teradata. I have created this code but there are lot of errors. Help appreciated!

**Current I manually code :**

```
select a_num,id from tablename union
select a_num,id from tablename_1912 union
select a_num,id from tablename_2001
```

Note: 1912, 2001 should be dynamic

**Expected:**

```
select a_num,id from tablename union 
select a_num,id from tablename_1912(dynamically change) union    
select a_num,id from tablename_2001(dynamically change)
```

**My Code:**

```
create procedure test_sp()
Create volatile table test(Account Number varchar(50),Id varchar(30) on commit preserve rows;

Begin 

Declare SQLL varchar(max);
Declare Schema_name_1 varchar(20);
Declare Schema_name_2 varchar(20);
Declare table_name varchar(30);
Declare underscore varhcar(10),
Declare 3_months_previous varchar(50);
Declare 2_months_previous varchar(50);

set schema_name_1 = 'Some_Schema_name1';
set schema_name_2 = 'Some_Schema_name2';
set table_name = 'test';
set 3_months_previous = substr(add_months(current_date,-3),3,2)||substr(add_months(current_date,-3),6,2);
set 2_months_previous = substr(add_months(current_date,-2),3,2)||substr(add_months(current_date,-2),6,2);
set underscore  = '_';
set SQLL = 'select A_Num,''11''+ from '+Schema_name_1+table_name+ ' union all '+
           'select B_Num,''22''+ from '+Schema_name_2+table_name+ ' union all '+
           'select A_Num,''23''+ from '+Schema_name_1+table_name+underscore+3_months_previous ' union all '+
           'select B_Num,''24''+ from '+Schema_name_2+table_name+underscore+2_months_previous ;

End;

insert into test
call test_sp();

select * from test t join another_Table c on t.a_num=c.p_num
```

Comment: I'm having a very difficult time understanding your question. Your sample code has multiple issues in it. There are lots of questions on SO about dynamic SQL in Teradata.  If those don't help you, try and rewrite your question so it's clearer.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I am trying to get dynamic table name. How Can I get dyanmic table name in teradata. I think I got title wrong

Comment: You have several typos in your code: `create procdure` and `Account Number varcahr(50)` and the structure of your stored procedure doesn't look quite right. 
 Take a look at the manual (https://docs.teradata.com/reader/CeAGk~BNtx~axcR0ed~5kw/Kau2_I7KwvqOYg0EJYkUTA) for a sample SP, fix up your typos and please re-post any error rmessages.

Comment: Hi Ravioli, I made a change but seems not working.
I am trying to create dyanamic table name and union those tables

Comment: The string concatenation operator in Teradata is `||` not `+`

Comment: Your question is too broad. Please concentrate your question on one issue you are facing. For example "I'm submitting the SPL but it's throwing error 'blah blah blah'". Asking us to rewrite this is a bit much. Some pointers though. 1) You have a CREATE TABLE statement preceding your `BEGIN` and `DECLARE` statements (it should follow those instead). 2)Creating a volatile table in a proc is tricky. Consider using SQL SECURITY OWNER or dynamically generating the vol table 3) Concatenate is `||` (which you are already using in a previous statement...

Comment: 4) Most importantly your schema is pretty awful. Instead of having many tables which only vary by the suffix number referring to the month, instead just have one table with an extra column to hold that month number for that record. Then you don't even need to build this crazy procedure.